# Trying to upload image using Karate REST API tool

Tags: api, testing, automated-tests, cucumber, karate

I m trying to upload two images in the post method, like this

[image]

but it's returning this error, the api didn't receive the uploads images

[image]

I want to know how is the correct approach to correct this problem

Comment: such questions are impossible to answer without a way to replicate. multipart requests are hard. refer to this thread please: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1645#issuecomment-862502881

Comment: @PeterThomas thank you for answering me, I just need to know how can I enter multiple photos in a Post method request what is the most explicated method for this issue

Comment: sorry, it's not that simple. you clearly have a `multipart` request. I also don't understand your question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @PeterThomas I'm putting in a new, clearer response

Comment: sorry I can't help. a lot depends on the server in this case which I personally don't know anything about. I suggest you work with someone on that team if possible. I have nothing to add besides the link I posted in my first comment, all the best

Comment: Question and details updated please could you check again, thanks